# React-Native app will not compile since adding react-native-google-place-picker node module

Tags: react-native, compiler-errors, android-emulator, node-modules, javac

I am a very new app developer, first job out of university and I'm working on a react-native app. My bosses have done some work on the app and then returned it to me. They added a node module called react-native-google-place-picker. And now I cannot get the app to compile and run on my emulator. It was working last week when I sent my work to them and they continued piecing all the devs work together.

Here is my console when I run react-native run-android, I am using Android studio emulator. I have been working on this app for a couple of weeks and been able to compile and test the app without any major issues but this one has me stumped.

Image of Error during compile:

[image: Image of Error during compile]

Comment: Can u provide your package.json?

Comment: Maybe running a gradle clean would help? Sometimes also trying to build it via Android Studio could provide more useful debug info

Comment: As @NoahAllen said run a gradle clean `cd android && gradlew clean` . When your boss added the new package did they run the app and did it work ? This seems like an issue with the google packages, some libraries in your app are using a different version causing the one used by `react-native-google-place-picker` to break

Comment: Regarding not being able to bill for hours when debugging, are you a freelancer? That does not sound like a sensible career path for someone just out of university. However, if you have been taken on as a permanent employee, do not accept a refusal to pay you for your debugging/learning time. Employers have a responsibility to train and nuture you - if they want someone to be productive immediately they should have hired a senior dev, and 2-3 times the salary.

Comment: They needed to present to a client this week and it did work on their end according to them, no compile error, I went with the work around and commented out the @Override. My changes were not directly related to the place picker as I was working on a different part of the app but I needed to compile to test my work. The work around worked for me and then when I sent my changes to them it worked on their side. So this time we got around it thanks!

Comment: @halfer you make a very good point and I think I have felt this to be the case so I have mentioned it to my bosses and have told them that with any future tasks I want to meet with them to have in depth discussions about the tasks and time/billing management. We're only a couple of months into the relationship and still working out the logistics but you have given me some confidence to back myself, thank you very much! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going into the RNGooglePlacePickerNode.java, and comment out the override statement.

Comment: Thanks, this worked to test my part of the app and its been sent back to my bosses.